# IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench - Running a test from the command line

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw, cmdline-args

I am trying to run a test from the command line using the cmdline.bat file, as suggested in https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/truncmdln.html

It is not like I am not getting some activity, but I haven't been able to understand how it properly works.

This is my current command:

> D:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.cmdlineexecute_
>   7.2.960.v20140710_1337>cmdline.bat -workspace C:\MobileFirstWorksp ace -project Test -eclipsehome D:\Eclipse\eclipse -plugins D:\Eclipse\eclipse\plugins -suite prueba2.testsuite -results
>   newResults

It runs for 45 to 72 seconds. My CommandLineLog.txt file shows the following:

> Adaptador convertido en instancia con D:\Programacion\Eclipse\eclipse
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. 2015-04-08
>   17:18:20.810:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031 2015-04-08
>   17:18:20.847:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:7878 2015-04-08
>   17:18:20.849:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:7080

But I can't find any results file, there are no results files in the directory I ran the command or either in the Test project folders. Does anyone know where should I find those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not a device connected to your workbench.

In order to get a result :

1. You should first launch RTW in the classical way with the ui.
2. Then you have to launch a simulator or a device and connect it to your workbench through the iOS Native or Web client (Of course, the instrumented app should be installed on the simu/device).
3. Siwtch to the passive mode (on the client).
4. You could now close the workbench.
5. Finally just launch your command line as you did before.

The workbench will start and wait for a client to be connected, ... after 30 seconds maximum the iOS Client (native or web) will connect to the workbench and the playback should start.

Hope it will help you.
Best regards, Alexandre.

Comment: It did not work at first, but it was because we did not run the test on the emulator before sending the cmdline request. Solved that with the Support Team.

Thank you very much Alexandre! You were right :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the reports are generated in your workspace and have the extension .moebreport (it's an zipped XML file)

You can ask to export it at the CLI with a preference. Open the prefs and go in Test > Performance Test Reports > Export Reports and select Command Line and Mobile and Web UI

Thanks.
Dominique

Comment: Hi Dom, we do not have the full Rational Test Workbench, just using the plugin available at the eclipse marketplace

Comment: This is the same for this plugin